# Python pandas: pad rows with missing/skipped date

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, datetime, timestamp, padding

I have the following data frame:

```
 date        my_count
--------------------------
2017-01-01         6
2017-01-04         5
2017-01-05         3
2017-01-08         8
```

I would like to pad the skipped date with `my_count = 0`, so the padded data frame will look like:

```
 date        my_count
--------------------------
2017-01-01         6
2017-01-02         0
2017-01-03         0
2017-01-04         5
2017-01-05         3
2017-01-06         0
2017-01-07         0
2017-01-08         8
```

Except checking the data frame line by line, is there a more elegant way to do this? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1st option `resample`,

```
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])
df = df.set_index('date')

print(df.resample('D').sum().fillna(0).reset_index())

        date  my_count
0 2017-01-01       6.0
1 2017-01-02       0.0
2 2017-01-03       0.0
3 2017-01-04       5.0
4 2017-01-05       3.0
5 2017-01-06       0.0
6 2017-01-07       0.0
7 2017-01-08       8.0
```

2nd option `reindex` by `date_range`,

```
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])
df = df.set_index('date')

print(df.reindex(pd.date_range('2017-01-01', '2017-01-08')).fillna(0))

            my_count
2017-01-01       6.0
2017-01-02       0.0
2017-01-03       0.0
2017-01-04       5.0
2017-01-05       3.0
2017-01-06       0.0
2017-01-07       0.0
2017-01-08       8.0
```

Comment: `reindex` has a `fill_value` parameter.  If you use it, you won't ever get `nan` an it will not get cast to float.  `df.reindex(pd.date_range('2017-01-01', '2017-01-08'), fill_value=0)`

Answer (score 1):

If values of `DatetimeIndex` are unique use:

You can use [`asfreq`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.asfreq.html) or [`reindex`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html) by min or max value of `index` or by first and last (if `DatetimeIndex` is sorted):

```
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])
df = df.set_index('date')

print(df.asfreq('D', fill_value=0).reset_index())
        date  my_count
0 2017-01-01         6
1 2017-01-02         0
2 2017-01-03         0
3 2017-01-04         5
4 2017-01-05         3
5 2017-01-06         0
6 2017-01-07         0
7 2017-01-08         8

rng = pd.date_range(df.index.min(), df.index.max())
#alternative
#rng = pd.date_range(df.index[0], df.index[-1])
print(df.reindex(rng, fill_value=0).rename_axis('date').reset_index())
        date  my_count
0 2017-01-01         6
1 2017-01-02         0
2 2017-01-03         0
3 2017-01-04         5
4 2017-01-05         3
5 2017-01-06         0
6 2017-01-07         0
7 2017-01-08         8
```

If `DatetimeIndex` are not unique get:

> ValueError: cannot reindex from a duplicate axis

Then need [`resample`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.resample.html) with some aggregate function like `mean` or [`groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) with [`Grouper`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Grouper.html) and last replace `NaN`s by  [`fillna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.fillna.html):

```
print (df)
         date  my_count
0  2017-01-01         4 <-duplicate date
1  2017-01-01         6 <-duplicate date
2  2017-01-04         5
3  2017-01-05         3
4  2017-01-08         8

df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])

print(df.resample('D', on='date')['my_count'].mean().fillna(0).reset_index())
        date  my_count
0 2017-01-01       5.0
1 2017-01-02       0.0
2 2017-01-03       0.0
3 2017-01-04       5.0
4 2017-01-05       3.0
5 2017-01-06       0.0
6 2017-01-07       0.0
7 2017-01-08       8.0

df = df.set_index('date')
print(df.groupby(pd.Grouper(freq='D'))['my_count'].mean().fillna(0).reset_index())
        date  my_count
0 2017-01-01       5.0
1 2017-01-02       0.0
2 2017-01-03       0.0
3 2017-01-04       5.0
4 2017-01-05       3.0
5 2017-01-06       0.0
6 2017-01-07       0.0
7 2017-01-08       8.0
```

Comment: Thanks! but I got this error: asfreq() got an unexpected keyword argument 'fill_value'     Any idea?

Comment: What is your pandas version? Foe me in `pandas 20.0.2` it works perfectly.